# How to verify that NSMutableArray of entity contains object with certain attribute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

Based on the data model here: Photographer<------->>Photo

When the user goes to add a `Photo`, the user also specifies what `Photographer` took said picture.  When the user decides to save the `Photo`, there is the possibility that the `Photographer` doesn't exist yet. After executing a NSFetchRequest to get a list of all instances of `Photographer`, how do I check if the NSMutableArray(photographerArray) contains an object that has the same `fullName` attribute as what the user is currently adding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive way would be to simply get all the `fullName` of the array and check if it's in it.

```
BOOL photographerExist = [[listOfPhotographer valueForKey:@"fullName"] containsObject:enteredFullName];
```

However, it would be way more easier to put that directly in your fetch request. Just add a [predicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) to it.

```
NSPredicate *fullNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fullName = %@", enteredFullName];
fetchRequest.predicate = fullNamePredicate;
```

If the result of the fetch is empty, then the photographer doesn't exist yet.